# How do I make my Icon appear on my IOS PhoneGap app when I export it for adhoc distribution?

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7

I have an app that an iOS app that I am creating using PhoneGap.  When I send it to my iPad for Ad-hoc distribution, the app icon and splash screen that I created do not appear.  How do I get them to appear on my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do this in Xcode, not Phonegap.

1. Open Xcode
2. Open your .codeproj file
3. Inside Xcode, open the file /Resources/-Info.plist

There you can see which icons and splash screens are being loaded into the proyect and change the values and/or the default icons.

Comment: It appears to be relative to the Resources/Icon Folder.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are developing for iOS 7?

Adding `<icon>` entries to your `config.xml` or editing the `*-Info.plist` file did not do it for me on iOS 7 using Cordova 3.1.0.

I had the same issue and solved it by using an Asset Catalog, a new feature in XCode 5 for managing images and icons. [**This guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH7-SW1) from the iOS Developer Library shows how to migrate your icons and splash screens to an asset catalog.